# How can Fix this

Tags: angular

How can I fix this error when calling **npm install** in the console:

```
krishan@krishan-Aspire-E1-571:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@6.0.8
[sudo] password for krishan: 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular- cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/krishan/.npm/_logs/2018-09-11T06_51_53_525Z-debug.log
```

Angular CLI: 6.0.8

Comment: What are you trying to do? 

P.S.: The answer is mentioned literally in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore this warning. The warning you've posted is for fsevents, which is an optional dependency only available on OS X.